# Pivot conditional formatting color do right only at 1st cell on range

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

If I try to set formatting color into a range of cell with this code:

```
Sub colora()
Dim rgn As Range
Set rgn = Range("E4:T8,E10:T16")
    rgn.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$W4=E$3"
    rgn.FormatConditions(rgn.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With rgn.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
    End With
    rgn.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True
    rgn.FormatConditions(1).ScopeType = xlSelectionScope
    rgn.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$Z4=E$3"
    rgn.FormatConditions(rgn.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With rgn.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
        .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
    End With
    rgn.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    rgn.FormatConditions(1).ScopeType = xlSelectionScope
End Sub
```

I play this macro but the result wrong, then I check the formatting function on ribbon tab I show that.

[image]

Why the range of applicable formatting change from `Range("E4:T8,E10:T16")`to E4?!?!

Comment: I was getting a runtime error on `rgn.FormatConditions(1).ScopeType = xlSelectionScope` so I commented that line out (in both spots) and the code ran fine and did the two different rules to the whole range.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvgGQ.png

Comment: @Chrismas007 that right, thank, the line rgn.FormatConditions(1).ScopeType = xlSelectionScope is made by macrorecorder, also I commented this line and the code work as I need. thank